# How to get liferay form name through code in java

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I am writing the code to fetch liferay forms through java but I am unable to do so. I am using recordset to do it but it is only fetching DDL recordset not forms.

```
public List<DDLRecordSet> getRecordSets()  {
        
        long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
        System.out.println("groupId:::"+groupId);
        long liveGroupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getLiveGroupId();
        
        System.out.println("LiveGroupID::"+ liveGroupId);
        

        List<DDLRecordSet> results = DDLRecordSetLocalServiceUtil.getRecordSets(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());
        if (liveGroupId != 0) {
            results.addAll(DDLRecordSetLocalServiceUtil.getRecordSets(groupId));
        }
        System.out.println("Result::"+ results);
             return result;

}
```

The output is shown only for DDL recordset not of form recordset.

Output=
Result::[{mvccVersion=0, uuid=7ca2308a-29f0-b344-8eeb-13eda08fe745, recordSetId=46003, groupId=20124, companyId=20101, userId=35402, userName=Test1 Test1, versionUserId=0, versionUserName=, createDate=Fri Jun 11 05:06:35 GMT 2021, modifiedDate=Fri Jun 11 05:06:35 GMT 2021, DDMStructureId=34991, recordSetKey=46002, version=1.0, name=, description=, minDisplayRows=10, scope=0, settings=, lastPublishDate=null}]

Please let me know where am I wrong.

Comment: What happens with the code you posted?

Comment: It only  returns recordset of dynamic data list present in liferay not of forms recordset

Comment: I think you should add that to your post. Add information necessary to answer your Question should be in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch all the created forms of a group/site, you can fetch the `DDMFormInstance`s via `DDMFormInstanceLocalServiceUtil.getFormInstances(groupId)` (or better to use osgi references instead). For me, it is not clear what is required in your scenario (form, form-fields, form-data).

If you want the submitted data (depending on your handler this might differ), you can usually look for the corresponding `DDMFormInstanceRecord` and check the storageId which might be contentId of DDMContent which holds your data (usually in json).

Comment: Thanks a lot it did worked.However I want to display formName which I have recieved  from DDMFormInstance, in dropdown at Jsf. Do you have any idea how to do it.